# How can my survivors get married?

Tags: stranded-alien-dawn

I'm playing "Stranded: Alien Dawn" (PC, via Steam). Two of my survivors have gotten engaged; the tutorial told me that in order for them to get married, I need to build a wedding arch.

I built the wedding arch, but nothing happened. Looking in the Steam discussion board, I found there's an 'event' that's supposed to occur (which a bunch of bugs and [workarounds](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1324130/discussions/0/3588835463361051853/) to actually get working), but I've not had any such an event occur. The survivors announced their engagement, but they never announced the marriage ceremony (the event).

How do I get these survivors married? They've been 'engaged' for over a year now.

Comment: Some people just like to take their time! There's nothing wrong with a long engagement! (I have no idea about the actual question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, they'll try to hold their wedding ceremony one year from the engagement announcement.

Note: ***try***. On the day in question - and you'll be informed when it is - at roughly evening the time window opens for both of them to join at the arch and as many other people as can make it to join them for the celebration.

It's *entirely* possible for one or another or both to be unable to make it before the window closes due to tasks, in which case they'll try again next year.

To avoid this, it's best to clear their permitted task lists on that day so they'll be free to come and get married.